# Scaling a UICollectionViewCell on selection

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Basically I want to scale a UICollectionViewCell when it is tapped.

I tried to fire the transformation like this:

```
    self.showPickerForIP = indexPath
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { 
                self.collView.reloadData()

            })
```

And size is managed like this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath == showPickerForIP{
        return CGSize(width: 320, height: 400)
    }
    else{
        return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    }
}
```

I have two problems:

**1. The format of the cells is wrong (as shown in the image)**

**2. It doesn't animate the transformation**

Before the transformation:
[image]

How it should look: 
[image]

How it actually looks like:
[image]

Comment: The black spots appearing between the cells, whoa

Comment: @Rikh what do you mean?